# Auth0 Jwt strange behavior

Tags: jwt, auth0

I want to use `jwt` as authentication mechanism so I pick `auth0-jwt` java libs. To implement authentication services I did a test about token validation. The test is simple, use this token:

```
{ "alg":"HS256", "typ": "JWT" } 
{ "sub": "dummySubject", "exp": "1498054620653" }
```

with `supersecretpassphrase` to verify signature. Given that token I expect back this (taken by jwt.io) one:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkdW1teVN1YmplY3QiLCJleHAiOiIxNDk4MDU0NjIwNjUzIn0.VTL9gIQ-POIoI8W0OI9y_Q7rDGFbniUGNcfd_EliK60
```

but test fails. The returned token is:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkdW1teVN1YmplY3QiLCJleHAiOjE0OTgwNTQ2MjB9.2dOy3HmWH7vMWiJoQvMOUsx2nR6l6phZ1nwIz-TSkNk
```

jwt.io says that that token has this shape:

```
{ "typ": "JWT", "alg": "HS256" }
{ "sub": "dummySubject", "exp": "1498054620" }
```

It looks like `exp` loose its milliseconds. This is how I fill my token:

```
private String computeToken(JwtToken token) throws Exception {
  Algorithm algorithmHS = Algorithm.HMAC256(passphrase);
  Date expirationTime = new Date(token.getExpirationTime().toInstant().toEpochMilli());
  Builder jwtToken = JWT.create().withSubject(token.getSubject()).withExpiresAt(expirationTime);
  Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> candidateClaimsIterator = token.getPayload().entrySet().iterator();
...
  return jwtToken.sign(algorithmHS);
}
```

The `JwtToken token` parameter is a simple bean I use to ship and validate data I want to put in token,

```
public class JwtToken implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @NotNull(message = "Subject can not be null")
  @Size(min = 10)
  private String subject;
  @NotNull(message = "Expiration time can not be null")
  private ZonedDateTime expirationTime;
  private Map<String, Object> payload;
  ...
  (getters and setters)
}
```

It seems that `java.util.Date` loose it's milliseconds while com.auth0.jwt.JWTCreator convert `exp` in a JSON string. Am I doing something wrong? Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: jwt uses seconds, not milliseconds, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593074/jwt-validation-fails/43605820#43605820 for details

Comment: @jps I totally missed that. Thankyou.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JWT Validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593074/jwt-validation-fails)