# Generating token for App Store Connect API

Tags: ruby, jwt, app-store-connect, itunes

I need to generate JWT token for [Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi). I'm trying use jwt ruby gem [ruby-jwt](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt). This is my token generating code,

```
payload = {
      'iss': my_issuer_id_from_db,
      'exp': generated_unix_timestamp, #Time.now + 20min
      'aud': 'hard_coded_string_from_doc'
  }
  header = {
      'alg': 'ES256',
      'kid': my_key_id_from_db,
      'typ': 'JWT'
  }

private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read('/tmp/private_key.pem'))
# private_key - <OpenSSL::PKey::EC:0x000000000XXXXXXX>

@token = JWT.encode(payload, private_key, 'ES256', header)
# encoded_header.encoded_payload.emcoded_signature
```

This token I put in to header of my request:

```
headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer' + @token }
```

in respons I receive:

```
        "errors": [{
                "status": "401",
                "code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
                "title": "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.",
                "detail": "Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens"
        }]
}
```

I thing the problem is with token(directly with signature). When I try decode token with [online tool](https://jwt.io/), my payload and header is decoded properly. Status: Invalid Signature

What I do wrong? Any ideas how do it properly?

Comment: 1. put a space between 'Bearer' and the token. The header should be 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ...'   2. on jwt.io, did you paste your key into the key field? Many people forget that and wonder why the tool says "Invalid signature"

Comment: I tried but jwt.io tool requires public and private keys. I have only private key.

Comment: The first point was the cause.

Comment: Hey, I'm also facing the same problem. How did you fix the issue? Could you be so nice as to share the whole ruby file? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I just created python3 version here. `401 Authentication credentials are missing or invalid` maybe related to getting time `issued` or `expired`.

Check your function get time is `UNIX epoch time` as Apple recommends.

```
import jwt
import datetime as dt

key_id = '#####' 
alg = 'ES256'
typ = 'JWT'
issue_id = '##########################'
aud = 'appstoreconnect-v1'
bid = '####' # Your app’s bundle ID (Ex: “com.example.testbundleid2021”)

# Define issue timestamp.
issued_at_timestamp = int(dt.datetime.now().timestamp())
# Define expiration timestamp. May not exceed 20 minutes from issue timestamp.
expiration_timestamp = issued_at_timestamp + 20*60

# Define JWT headers.
headers = dict()
headers['alg'] = alg
headers['kid'] = key_id
headers['typ'] = typ

# Define JWT payload.
payload = dict()
payload['iss'] = issue_id
payload['iat'] = issued_at_timestamp
payload['exp'] = expiration_timestamp
payload['aud'] = aud
payload['bid'] = bid
# Path to signed private key.
KEY_FILE = '#########.p8' 

with open(KEY_FILE,'r') as key_file:
     key = ''.join(key_file.readlines())

client_secret = jwt.encode(
payload=payload,  
headers=headers,
algorithm=alg,  
key=key
)

with open('client_secret.txt', 'w') as output: 
     output.write(client_secret)
    
    
# Usage, after run this code by python3
# get token from `client_secret.txt` and replace to [signed token]
# Remember expired time maximum is 20 minutes
#
# curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [signed token]' "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps"
#
# More detail https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests
```

Comment: A few changes I had to make: The addition of `payload['bid'] = bid` where bid is your app bundle ID. For newbies like me `[signed token]` is the content of the file, not `client_secret.txt` :D. Finally, you need to make a `POST` request with one of the proper URL, production or sandbox. Here is my curl request for sandbox: `curl -X POST -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/notifications/test`. Check the doc if necessary: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/request_a_test_notification.

Comment: @lorenzo thank you. I've updated `bid` in the payload.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar kind of authentication error i.e. *NOT_AUTHORIZED*. And I resolved it by following these steps:

## 1. Create Ruby Script file to generate valid `Bearer` Token:

*Ref:* https://medium.com/xcblog/generating-jwt-tokens-for-app-store-connect-api-2b2693812a35

```
require "base64"
require "jwt"
ISSUER_ID = "YOUR_ISSUER_ID"
KEY_ID = "YOUR PRIVATE KEY ID"    // this is ID part from downloaded .p8 file name (see below for ref.)
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read(path_to_your_private_key/AuthKey_#{KEY_ID}.p8))   // you can enclose your file path in quotes if needed, and can pass here totally static file path (here we are reusing Key_ID variable)

token = JWT.encode(
   {
    iss: ISSUER_ID,
    exp: Time.now.to_i + 20 * 60,
    aud: "appstoreconnect-v1"
   },
   private_key,
   "ES256",
   header_fields={
       kid: KEY_ID }
)
puts token
```

Then run this script with following command on your Mac.

`$ ruby jwt.rb`

This will display a valid `Bearer` token on your terminal screen, that you can use in next step.

> *Notes:*
>
> - In order to run above script, you'll need to have `ruby` installed.
> - You'll copy Issuer ID from you Developer account. Generate one if you don't have it.
> - Make sure you are using '.p8' certificate against authenticated user, which means the account against which you downloaded '.p8' certificate should have permission to perform API level operation. For my case I used *Admin* type account. Initially I was using *Developer* type user account which kept giving me *Not_Authorized* error when I go for final Curl call to get the token.

## 2. Using Token:

Now that, we have seen how to generate a token to access an App Store Connect API, we can use it by passing authorization header. e.g to get a list of all user we can use

```
$ curl  https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users --Header "Authorization: Bearer lOOOOOOOOOOOONG_GENERATED_TOKEN"
```

This will list all the users of App Store Connect. Remember that we have to use this token with every request we make and we have to create new token after every 20 minutes.

Comment: This example copy pasted from the xcblog at https://medium.com/xcblog/wwdc18-a-basic-guide-to-app-store-connect-api-366208651ac6 does not work even after removing comments and filling in legit values. It probably has to do with the way header_fields is not used. (Try rubocop on the file.)

Comment: Ensure JWT gem is installed for the script to work `sudo gem install jwt`

Answer (score 2):

You had a missing space in your authorization string passed in. You code worked fine when modified to

`headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + @token }`

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer from 2023 that leverages the Ruby script in @Nah's answer, but worked for me because it adds some keys that are missing in the old answer.

Ruby script:

```
require "base64"
require "jwt"
ISSUER_ID = "YOUR-ISSUER-ID"
KEY_ID = "YOUR-KEY-ID"
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read("PATH_TO_KEY_DOWNLOADED_FROM_APP_STORE_CONNECT.p8"))
token = JWT.encode(
  {
    iss: ISSUER_ID,
    exp: Time.now.to_i + 20 * 60,
    aud: "appstoreconnect-v1",
    bid: "YOUR_BUNDLE_ID"
  },
  private_key,
  "ES256",
  header_fields = {
    alg: "ES256",
    kid: KEY_ID,
    typ: "JWT"
  }
)
puts token
```

You can then take that key and put it in an `Authorization` header when communicating with Apple.

For example, I needed to get a test notification from Apple for in-app purchase events, so I can put the token in a curl request and get a 200:

```
curl -v --request POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_LONG_TOKEN_HERE" \
"https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/notifications/test"
```

If you would prefer to use Postman, in the `Authorization` tab, set a `Bearer Token` to the token that the Ruby script generated.