# NestJS JwtService verifyToken() reads wrong 'nbf' JWT date

Tags: javascript, jwt, nestjs

I'm using a JwtService in a NestJS app. Jwt is initialized like so:

```
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
// ...
JwtModule.register({
    secret: 'mysecret', // TODO: Change to production injected value.
    signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
}),
```

I created a Jwt and signed it like so:

```
import { JwtService, JwtSignOptions } from '@nestjs/jwt';

// ...

constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
) {}

// ...

const userInfo = {
    email: user.email,
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName
};
const accessTokenPayload = {
    iss: 'Auth Server 3.2',     // Issuer
    sub: user.id.toString(),    // Subject (user ID)
    aud: ['myClient'],          // Audience (recipient(s))
    exp: (new Date()).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // Expiration time (Unix timestamp)
    nbf: (new Date()).getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000,
    iat: new Date().getTime(),              // Issued at (Unix timestamp)
    jti: randomBytes(32).toString('hex'),   // JWT ID (unique identifier)
    data: { userInfo }
}
const accessToken = this.jwtService.signAsync(accessTokenPayload);
```

This results in the following token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJBdXRoIFNlcnZlciAzLjIiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwiYXVkIjpbIm15Q2xpZW50Il0sImV4cCI6MTY4MzE4Nzc4OTIzNSwibmJmIjoxNjgzMDk3Nzg5MjM1LCJpYXQiOjE2ODMxMDEzODkyMzUsImp0aSI6ImM5ZTIwY2E5ODAwNzEzNGUyNWFmNjk3MzZmZTIyOGM3MTQyNzBhMWQ1NWY5OGFjOWVjZTU2NmQxOTAyYWJiYzUiLCJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXJJbmZvIjp7ImVtYWlsIjoidXNlckBlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJKb2huIiwibGFzdE5hbWUiOiJTbWl0aCJ9fX0.WSJsnzsZNrMPOQLuPbDoeigFeB6IRJFmXo2qUSFCi3k
```

which has the following payload:

```
{
  "iss": "Auth Server 3.2",
  "sub": "1",
  "aud": [
    "myClient"
  ],
  "exp": 1683187789235,
  "nbf": 1683097789235, // valid nbf value = 2023-05-03T07:09:49.235Z
  "iat": 1683101389235,
  "jti": "c9e20ca98007134e25af69736fe228c714270a1d55f98ac9ece566d1902abbc5",
  "data": {
    "userInfo": {
      "email": "user@email.com",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

**The Problem:** (Please read carefully because this is not a duplicate question)

When verifying the JWT by this code:

```
try {
    await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(accessToken);
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Error', e)
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error NotBeforeError {
        name: 'NotBeforeError',
        message: 'jwt not active',
        date: +055303-05-11T16:49:49.000Z  // --> note the invalid nbf value
}
```

**Note the odd future date in year 55303: `date: +055303-05-11T16:49:49.000Z` for the `nbf` field.** = 'Fri, 11 May 55303 16:49:49 GMT'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

PS:

1. Commenting the nbf field solves this, but I lose the ability to validate that the token is not used before a certain date.
2. Choosing a different value for nbf (ex. `nbf: 1683097789235` that is equal to `2023-05-03T07:09:49.235Z`) gives the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs jwt token never expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555829/nodejs-jwt-token-never-expires)

Comment: @jps no, note that the time stamp being passed to the signing function is valid and equal `nbf: 1683038191789`, and `new Date(1683038191789) = 2023-05-02T14:36:31.789Z`

Comment: I added the payload where you can see the actual valid `nbf` field in the signed jwt payload

Comment: Did you, as described in the linked answer, copy the token to jwt.io to inspect it and hover the mouse over the timestamp to see the value? If not, please do it now. And then please delete the last 3 digits of the timestamp and see what comes out now. The problem is, in JS the UNIX timestamp is based on milliseconds, but the JWT standard requires UNIX time in seconds. That's what my linked answer tries to explain.

Comment: And the solution in your code is to simply delete the `* 1000` part in the calculation of the timestamps.

Comment: Thanks so much, the input parameters for the jwt is wrong and should be changed, and inspecting the `jwtTimestamp` value by `new Date(jwtTimestamp)` to get the date is wrong. Unfortunately this is not clear in the answer of the provided link. I suggest to write a dedicated clear answer to this question and leave it open in order to help others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the date input parameters given for the signing method:

```
exp: (new Date()).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  
nbf: (new Date()).getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000,
iat: new Date().getTime(),
```

Even though these values (from the encoded JWT) translate to valid dates when creating a new javascript dates from them:

```
"exp": 1683187789235, // new Date(1683187789235) = 2023-05-04T08:09:49.235Z = valid date
"nbf": 1683097789235, // new Date(1683097789235) = 2023-05-03T07:09:49.235Z = valid date
"iat": 1683101389235, // new Date(1683101389235) = 2023-05-03T08:09:49.235Z = valid date
```

The values are **not valid JWT dates**, because the JWT standard requires UNIX time in *seconds*, while in JS the UNIX timestamp is based on *milliseconds*.

Therefore, the answer to the question is to convert the Dates provided to the jwt siging function (`signAsync`) from milliseconds to seconds, like so:

```
const accessTokenPayload = {
    iss: 'Auth Server 3.2',     // Issuer
    sub: user.id.toString(),    // Subject (user ID)
    aud: ['myClient'],          // Audience (recipient(s))
    exp: Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000),  // Expiration time (Unix timestamp)
    nbf: Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000),
    iat: Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime()) / 1000),              // Issued at (Unix timestamp)
    jti: randomBytes(32).toString('hex'),   // JWT ID (unique identifier)
    data: { userInfo }
}
```

**Note:** To check the actual values of the a timestamp in a JWT, don't use `new Date(valueFromJwt)`, but rather use https://jwt.io/ and hover over the time fileds to see how the jwt interprets the date:
[image]