# How to set long expiry to JWT Token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

```
 private string GenerateJSONWebToken(pswd user)
 {
     var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
     var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
     var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
         _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
         null,
         expires: DateTime.Now.AddYears(100),
         signingCredentials: credentials);
            
     return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
  }
```

Here I am adding expiry of token to be after 100 years.
I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGFOY.png)

The generated token is correct , I debugged it and checked the expiry date which was after 100 years . But the token which is generated is not working and not able to access the data from the web api which it is intended for.
The maximum value I can add to expiry is up to 10 years , till that the generated token is working perfectly find . It is able to fetch data properly with 200 response code.

How can I can set lifetime validity to jwt token and why I am getting error as "no expiry" when even I set expiry to 100 years or more .

Comment: Why do you need a token with such expiration date?

Comment: If what do you need is preventing a human renewal token you should use the refresh oauth refresh token: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593074/jwt-validation-fails) explain the error that you got.

Comment: I tested with your code and IIS server(except the issuer), and didn't run into the issue, you could use another server to test if it is server limit and share your config code or how you send the request.

Comment: I am developing this web Api on my local computer . How do I change the server ?

Comment: I just wanted to check for how long can we keep jwt valid . Currently I am able to issue a token upto 10 years of validity .

Comment: I can't reproduce it but found some explanations that are about Year 2038 bug as jps mentioned . You could verify if it is the framework of unix time and thus runs into this issue. If so it will be valid until 2038 .

Comment: I guess the problem really lies with the year 2038 . It cannot go beyond date 19 Jan 2038 due to unix epcoh time problem. Does anyone has workaround that ?

Answer (score 1):

The expiration date is there for security reasons. I would possibly rather look into how to extend it when users are active, or a refresh token perhaps.

Comment: Yes you are right about that , but for demonstration or testing purpose I was trying to set it . Then got to know about 2038 bug .